# comparing a map and returning right value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve a double value from my map however the data is coming back in array form e.g. `[value]`. What am i doing wrong? I want the original value to be returned without the []. I can convert to a string, remove then convert it but that is messy

```
List<Map<Object,List<Map<String,Object>>>> tempValues = new ArrayList<Map<Object,List<Map<String,Object>>>>()

        for (Map<Object,List<Map<String,Object>>> map : tempValues) {   
            List<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
                for (Entry<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    for(int i =0;  i < entry.getValue().size(); i++)
                        temp.add(entry.getValue().get(i).values());
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: yes, have updated my answer

Comment: Can you provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" code that we can actually run and test in our machines.Then we can fix the code and post you back.

Comment: have updated again .. just hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: `tempValues.get(index).get(key).get(index2).get(key)`  << This will access a `Double` in your nested data structures. Of course, you will need to know what the keys and indices are.

Comment: Have updated my question but, i am still unable to retrieve the correct value. any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: `entry.getValue().get(i).values()` gives you an array of all the values stored in the map. If you want just a specific value, I suggest getting it using its key. If you don't know the key, you will need to know the index in the array of values. Assuming there is only one value in the array of values, you could do: `entry.getValue().get(i).values().get(0)` to get the `Double`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this extremely nested set of lists and maps? I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: would it be possible to show me an example of this? i nested it to get the size of the array as it will vary .. but why is my value returned as an array?

Comment: Your value is returned as an array because, as I explained previously, `.values()` returns an array of all values in the map. You have to select one of those values from the array to get just a single value. Check out the `Map` api for more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Yes, so values() returns [[value],[value]]. values().get(0) returns [value] (still an array) so what am i missing?

Comment: Then you must be storing an array as the value.

Comment: im not but the below answer works. thanks anways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(func());

}

public static List<Double> func() {
    List<Double> dblList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<Object, List<Map<String, Double>>> map : list) {
        for (List<Map<String, Double>> list : map.values()) {
            for (Map<String, Double> map1 : list) {
                for (Double dbl : map1.values()) {
                    dblList.add(dbl);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dblList;
}
```